# Extract directory name and leaf name from a given URL

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, url, uri, string-formatting

Example URL1: `http://example/dirname/subdirname/leafname`
        URL2: `http://example:5678/dirname/leafname`

From the above examples Directory names are "dirname/subdirname" & "dirname" and 
                        Leaf names are "leafname" & "leafname"

Basically Directory name is everything before the last '/' and Leaf name being everything after last '/' in the Absolute Path

I've tried to use `AbsolutePath.substring(1, AbsolutePath.LastIndexof('/')-1)` for directory name and `AbsolutePath.substring(AbsolutePath.LastIndexof('/')+1, AbsolutePath.Length - DirectoryName.Length)` for Leaf name.

But this is not working in all the cases. Can I know if there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. The Directory name is correct, but you need to start from 0 instead of 1 (else you'll end up with `ttp://`)

```
string directory = AbsolutePath.Substring(1, AbsolutePath.LastIndexOf('/') - 1);
```

For the leaf name, you don,t need the second argument :

```
string leaf = AbsolutePath.Substring(AbsolutePath.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

So with your example :

```
string AbsolutePath = "http://example/dirname/subdirname/leafname";
string directory = AbsolutePath.Substring(1, AbsolutePath.LastIndexOf('/') - 1); //From http to subdirname
string leaf = AbsolutePath.Substring(AbsolutePath.LastIndexOf('/') +  1); //leafname
```

Also, if you wish to keep the last `/` in the dirname, you just need to remove the -1

```
AbsolutePath.Substring(1, AbsolutePath.LastIndexOf('/'));
```

Comment: I've having trouble when there is no directory name or leaf name in the URL. I get a error in "substring" function